# Certbot fails using nginx under XUbuntu

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, nginx

Following instructions from https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/how-to-host-a-static-website-with-nginx-8b2dd0c5b301, I instead installed python3-certbot-nginx instead of python-certbot-nginx. Is that correct?
I got this error: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem).
I've got port forwarding on my router to the appropriate computer for ports 80 & 8080, and I've got ufw showing for nginx Full, nginx HTTP & nginx HTTPS. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest posting your question directly to the LetsEncrypt community support site: https://community.letsencrypt.org/ I usually get excellent and prompt responses to my questions about certbot there.

Comment: @Chris Heath I posted to LetsEncrypt Community yesterday. No replies yet.

Comment: I'm losing my marbles. I meant to post yesterday to the LetsEncrypt community yesterday evening but I forgot!

Comment: My mistake. After the Certbot engineer replied, I realised what I had done wrong. I used rose.ddns.me rather than rose.myddns.me for my website address. After changing filenames & file contents etc, everything Ok except that Firefox thinks that my Security Certificate is untrustworthy because it is self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. After the Certbot engineer replied, I realised what I had done wrong. I used rose.ddns.me rather than rose.myddns.me for my website address. After changing filenames & file contents etc, everything Ok except that Firefox thinks that my Security Certificate is untrustworthy because it is self-signed.

Comment: I forgot to get the router to forward port 443. Everything now Ok.